# Concat two arrays retuning circular js

Tags: javascript

I have an array (JSON objects):

```
result = [[{object},{object}], [{object}], [{object},{object},{object}]]
```

And I am trying to get it into a single array of objects:

```
array = [{object},{object},{object}],{object},{object},{object}]
```

However no matter which method I try I something like is output from console.log(array):

```
  [{object}, [circular], {object}, [circular], [circular] etc
```

I have no idea what circular like this is?

```
 var array = [];

    for (var i=0; i<result.length;i++) {
        array = array.concat(result[i]);
    }
```

or:

```
  for (var i=0; i<result.length;i++) {
           var res = result[i];
           for (var x=0; x<res.length; x++){
               array.push(res[x]);
           }
       }
```

Comment: what is this circular thing? where do these logs come from?

Comment: Can you give examples of exactly what the objects are? [I've tested your code](https://jsfiddle.net/yguuuxvp/) and it works just fine for me as long as its always an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the initial array contains only 2 levels as your example (no elements inside arrays are arrays), this would work:

```
var array = result.reduce(function(a,b){
    return a.concat(b);
});
```

using *reduce* and *concat* does the trick, returning all elements in a single array.

Comment: Lots of great answers, but simple and effective. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need some recursive function which is pushing elements in an accumulator. 
When it's not an array, simply push it, otherwise, push its components:

```js
var isArray = function(someVar) {
   return Object.prototype.toString.call( someVar ) === '[object Array]';
};

var flattenArrayAux = function(arr, accum) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    if(isArray(arr[i])) {
      flattenArrayAux(arr[i], accum);
    }
    else {
      accum.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
}

var flattenArray = function(arr) {
  var result = [];
  flattenArrayAux(arr, result);
  return result;
}

document.write(flattenArray([[1, 2, 3], 4, [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I properly understand your question, you need something like this:

```js
var arrays = [[{a:1},{b: 2}], [{c:3}], [{d: 4},{e: 5},{f: 6}]];

function flattenArray(arr, result) {
    var res = result || [];

    arr.forEach(function(item){
        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
            flattenArray(item, res)
        } else {
            res.push(item)
        }
    })

    return res;
}

console.log(flattenArray(arrays))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [lodash flattenDepth](https://lodash.com/docs#flattenDepth)

```
array = [ [object,object], [object], [object,object,object] ]

_.flattenDepth(array, 1);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/06f4L5hr/3/)